# How to draw a simple grid/grill in the background using the R package 'grid'?

Tags: r, r-grid

I would like to construct a grid object for a background behind a base graphics plot. When drawn, it should simply colorize the background in gray and put a red grid/grill on this background. The following shows a trial, but the grid obviously doesn't see the correct 'window'/viewport... How can this be achieved?

```
require(grid)
require(gridBase)

## function to compute a "background grob" (gray background with red 'grid')
bgGrob <- function(v, h, col, fill, default.units="npc", vp=NULL)
{
    ## background
    br <- rectGrob(gp=gpar(col=NA, fill=fill), vp=vp) # background rectangle

    ## grid: construct grobs
    vl <- segmentsGrob(x0=v, y0=0, x1=v, y1=1, # vertical lines
                       default.units=default.units, gp=gpar(col=col), vp=vp)
    hl <- segmentsGrob(x0=0, y0=h, x1=1, y1=h, # horizontal lines
                       default.units=default.units, gp=gpar(col=col), vp=vp)
    ## grid: pack grobs
    fg <- frameGrob(vp=vp) # set up basic frame grob (for packing)
    u1 <- unit(1, units=default.units)
    fg <- packGrob(fg, br, col=1, row=1, # background rectangle
                   width=u1, height=u1, force.width=TRUE)
    fg <- packGrob(fg, vl, col=1, row=1, # vertical lines
                   width=u1, height=u1, force.width=TRUE)
    fg <- packGrob(fg, hl, col=1, row=1, # horizontal lines
                   width=u1, height=u1, force.width=TRUE)
    fg
}

## data
x <- 1:10
y <- rev(x)

## layout
grid.newpage()
gl <- grid.layout(nrow=1, ncol=1, widths=0.8, heights=0.8,
                  default.units="npc")
pushViewport(viewport(layout=gl))
vp <- viewport(layout.pos.row=1, layout.pos.col=1)
pushViewport(vp)

par(plt=gridPLT())
par(new=TRUE)

## set up coordinate system
plot.window(range(x), range(y), log="y")

v <- axTicks(1, axp=par("xaxp"), log=par("xlog")) # x values of vertical lines (2, 4, 6, 8, 10)
h <- axTicks(2, axp=par("yaxp"), log=par("ylog")) # y values of horizontal lines (1, 2, 5, 10)
## => correct values

## background
## trial 1
grid.draw(bgGrob(v=v, h=h, col="red", fill="gray90", default.units="native",
                 vp=grid::dataViewport(x, y)))
## trial 2
## grid.draw(bgGrob(v=v, h=h, col="red", fill="gray90", default.units="native"))

## trial 3
## grid.draw(bgGrob(v=v, h=h, col="red", fill="gray90", vp=vp, default.units="native"))

## plot
plot(x, y, type="b", log="y")

popViewport()
```

**UPDATE**

Based on Baptiste's first answer, here is a more complete minimal example (with 'Q' addressing follow-up questions):

```
require(grid)
require(gridBase)

bgGrob <- function(v, h, gp=gpar(fill="grey90", col="red"), vp=NULL)
    grobTree(rectGrob(),
             segmentsGrob(v, unit(0, "npc"), v, unit(1, "npc")),
             segmentsGrob(unit(0, "npc"), h, unit(1, "npc"), h),
             vp=vp, gp=gp)

## data
x <- 1:10
y <- rev(x)

## layout, par (for using base graphics)
plot.new()
gl <- grid.layout(nrow=1, ncol=1, widths=0.8, heights=0.8,
                  default.units="npc")
pushViewport(viewport(layout=gl))
vp <- viewport(layout.pos.row=1, layout.pos.col=1)
pushViewport(vp)
par(plt=gridPLT(), new=TRUE)

## set up coordinate system
plot.window(range(x), range(y), log="y")

## get tick locations
v <- axTicks(1, axp=par("xaxp"), log=par("xlog")) # x values of vertical lines
h <- axTicks(2, axp=par("yaxp"), log=par("ylog")) # y values of horizontal lines

## draw background
grid.draw(bgGrob(v=v, h=h, vp=viewport(width=1, height=1))) # Q: where are the red grill lines?

## draw base graphics on top of the background
plot(x, y, type="b", log="y")

## (check +) finalize
grid.rect(gp=gpar("blue")) # Q: why is nothing drawn?
popViewport()
```

Comment: why do you want to do this using a mix of base and grid graphics? What's the end-goal of this function? I'm asking because many of the steps seem unnecessary and suboptimal at the same time.

Comment: Hi Baptiste, thank you for your help. We essentially want to construct a specific plot using grid (whenever possible), but the user can provide a specific base graphics plot which we use as 'input' (this is why we mix base with grid graphics). For the background, we would like to construct a function which returns a grob providing a background with 'grill'/grid. This is first drawn, after which the user provided base graphic is plotted. [we have reasons to do it like this, e.g., it's simpler for the user and works better with certain logarithmic axes (not available in grid/ggplot/lattice)]

Comment: in that case why not make the background in base graphics as well? (e.g. http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=tips:graphics-misc:ggplot2theme_inbase)

Comment: actually, that's exactly what we had :-). I saw it as 1) an exercise to learn more about grid and 2) use the function that returns the "background grob" in the longer run in other (grid) graphics we have. The idea is also, in the longer run, to provide an alternative function which is 'grid-only'. For this we also need a "background grob function"

Comment: what's the packGrob stuff for? Why not use a simple gTree?

Comment: I thought one either needs 1) a layout to which one adds grobs or 2) use a frameGrob and packs/places grobs to it (essentially internally using a layout). If you know a simpler solution (with gTrees), I'd be happy to learn about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I initially thought you needed `baseViewports()`, but it looks like `par("usr")` gives you enough information to set up a grid viewport with the coordinates system corresponding to the axes. Note that log scales require extra care. I still think this is a bad idea; it will probably break as soon as you place non-trivial base graphics. One is usually much better off not mixing the two systems.

```
require(grid)
require(gridBase)

bgGrob <- function(v, h, gp=gpar(fill="grey90", col="red"), vp=NULL, def="native")
  grobTree(rectGrob(),
           segmentsGrob(v, unit(0, "npc"), v, unit(1, "npc"), def=def),
           segmentsGrob(unit(0, "npc"), h, unit(1, "npc"), h, def=def),
           vp=vp, gp=gp)

grid.bg = function(...)
  grid.draw(bgGrob(...))

## data
x <- 1:10
y <- rev(x)

## layout, par (for using base graphics)
grid.newpage()
plot.new()
gl <- grid.layout(nrow=1, ncol=1, widths=0.8, heights=0.8,
                  default.units="npc")
pushViewport(viewport(layout=gl))
vp <- viewport(layout.pos.row=1, layout.pos.col=1)
pushViewport(vp)
par(plt=gridPLT(), new=TRUE)

## set up coordinate system
plot.window(range(x), range(y), log="y")
# suppressWarnings(base <- baseViewports())
## get tick locations
v <- axTicks(1, axp=par("xaxp"), log=par("xlog")) # x values of vertical lines
h <- axTicks(2, axp=par("yaxp"), log=par("ylog")) # y values of horizontal lines

if(par("xlog")) v <- log10(v)
if(par("ylog")) h <- log10(h)

usr <- par("usr")
## draw background
grid.bg(v=v, h=h, vp=viewport(xscale=usr[1:2], yscale=usr[3:4]))

## draw base graphics on top of the background
plot(x, y, type="b", log="y")
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, Baptiste. Do you know why the red lines overplot the line now?

Comment: they don't, but the points are hollow. Set lwd=20, cex=5 and you'll see that the red lines are below.

Comment: sorry for that, I stared at the screen for too long :-)

Many thanks for helping, Baptiste (as usual).